# Problems adding values to ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, addition

I'm trying to add url values (imgURL variable) taken from JSON into an ArrayList with Kotlin, but somehow when in the scope of the for loop it doesn't seem to work regardless of having my newArrayURLs array declared as a function variable. Any ideas why is this?

```
private fun getJsonObjectImg(Url: String): ArrayList<String>{

    var paths: ArrayList<String> =ArrayList()

    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    var newArrayURLs = ArrayList<String>()

    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, Response.Listener { s ->
        try {

            val array = JSONObject(s)
            var imagesArray = array.getJSONArray("images")

            for(i in 0..imagesArray.length() -1 ){
                var imgURL = imagesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fileName")
                newArrayURLs.add(imgURL)
                paths.add(imgURL)

            }

            Log.d("pathsin TRY", paths.count().toString())

        } catch(e:JSONException){
            Log.d("ERROR------", e.toString())

            null
        }

        }, Response.ErrorListener {
        error: VolleyError? ->
        try {
            Log.d("ERROR======","V")
        } catch (e: JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }) {
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> = mapOf("uploadedBy" to id)

    }
    val  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)

    return newArrayURLs

}
```

Comment: The method sends a request, and registers a listener, that will be invoked, asynchronously, a long time after the mehod has returned, when the HTTP response finally comes back. So, when you return the list, the listener hasn't been called yet, and the returned list is thus empty.

Comment: You are correct, now I'm trying to establish a co-routine  with Thread.sleep right before the return but doesn't seem to work.